# Need way to change column name in tabular model without breaking reports

Tags: tabular

Question about the new Microsoft Analysis Services Tabular Model.

Once the model is deployed and reports are created against it (e.g., in PowerView or Excel), what if you need to change the name of a column?  As far as I can tell, there is no way to change the name of the column in the tabular model without breaking the attached reports that utilize that column.

In most OLAP tools, there is a "friendly name" or "caption" field that is separate from the actual source column.  Sometimes this is the difference between the physical versus business layers in semantic modeling tools.  Can you get this type of functionality out of the tabular model yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the name of the column without breaking the report.  Buy you can have the give your tabular model column a different name than what's in the source data -- that's about as good as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only other textual field a column can have is the description field and this field is purely for internal use and is unavailable in the power view or excel UI.